# My external keyboard keys are not functioning properly

Tags: keyboard

OK so i just got my external keyboard in the mail but when I use it the keys are acting very very weird because when I press <kbd>u</kbd> it puts **4** on the screen etc... so how do I change my actual keys? I've tried looking in the settings but I need help!